# Azure PaaS for Storing Centralized Log Data for Microservices

Tags: azure, error-logging, azure-aks

If we deploy a Microservice in azure AKS,  there may be multiple pods and replica of same services. If Microservice want to keep any custom log information about it's flow or errors ,  where better to store such logs centrally?  Any PaaS services?  e. g. Azure Storage? Any real experience to share here?

Comment: Application Insights?

Comment: We able to write and store Logs in to Application Insights? What I knew that Application Insight will generate it's own logs on Application and not accepting Logs written from Application.

Comment: You can use the Application Insight SDK to write your own logs in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [Azure Application Insigths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview). You can enrich your telemetry with aks details using [this integration package](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes):

> ... when using Microsoft Application Insights for Kubernetes, you will see Kubernetes related properties like Pod-Name, Deployment ... on all your telemetry entries. Proper values will also be set to make use of the rich features like enabling the Application Map to show the multiple micro services on the same map.

For logging within your application you can use the `ILogger` interface (if using .net) and pipe it [to app insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger).

Or you can write your own logging using [the sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics), available in selected languages.

For java applications, you can pipe your logs [as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-trace-logs). You probably have to manually add pod details to your telemetry using [telemetry initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#java-telemetry-initializers) as the Microsoft Application Insights for Kubernetes package is .Net only. As far as I know they use the kubernetes rest api to query for details.

Comment: Thanks for giving an insight in to this. Is there restriction in case of Java based apps/ services deployed in AKS to use Application Insight?

Comment: No, except that the Microsoft Application Insights for Kubernetes package is .Net only. I've update my answer